# How do Syndicates work?

Tags: warframe

How do Syndicates work? The site says I can only be tied to one Syndicate at a time, does it mean I can't switch to any other one and my choice is permanent? If I want rewards in the other Syndicate could I leave my current Syndicate and take them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syndicates are far less formally bonding than you have been told - it comes down to a few things.

### Faction Sigils

The easiest way to gain reputation with a faction (Syndicate) is to equip their Sigil on your Warframe, and gain XP. For every 30xp (might need to check this) gained, you gain 1 reputation with that faction - and with the higher level sigils, you will gain a slightly higher amount (up to +15%).

You get the initial faction sigils from the initial offering to a faction, and you can do this initial offering for all of the factions with no negative penalty.

### Daily Missions

After the second offering for a given faction, you will get three missions available that refresh at Midnight (UTC). These offer a fixed amount of reputation for completion, and don't count towards you daily reputation cap.

### Negative Reputation

The reason you might have thought you can only be in one faction at a time is possibly due to the Allied / Enemy system - some factions 'dislike' each other, and gaining positive reputation with one will give you negative reputation with another.
In practice, this means that you can probably expect to keep three factions happy, and be hated by the other three.

### TL;DR

You can level any syndicate by simply wearing their sigil, which you get by making the initial payment - you'll get dailies to do after another level. There's nothing keeping you to a single syndicate bar common sense.

Hope that helps.